# Device Specific Javascript, preferably JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have a pretty Jquery-heavy site in the rollout. However, since it uses fullscreen backgrounds ... which are pretty useless on mobile devices I would love to deactivate the Jquery plugin on mobile devices...

I tried to research this problem but did not came up with a simple solutions...

Media queries won't really do... since there's too much reliance upon Javascript... 
media Queries are CSS-only right (I am more a designer than a programmer.... )

Answer (score 0):

u will have to detect wether its a mobile device using tools like WURFL and then deactivate it.

Comment: I would be already happy with a media query like deactivation of javascript/Jquery plugins ... like eg. window-width < 960 ...